Setting ag grid date filter in range default dates
I'm trying to set "from" and "to" dates as default in range option. Simple as that and impossible to find working piece of code that does this simple thing.
Working on angular 17 and ag grid latest (32.3.3)
My filterParams:
filterParams: {
 buttons: ['apply', 'reset'],
 maxNumConditions: 1,
 closeOnApply: true,
 defaultOption: 'inRange',
 filterOptions: ['inRange']
}


setDateFilter() {
  this.gridApi
  .setColumnFilterModel("NAME_OF_COLID", {
    conditions: [
      {
        type: "inRange",
        dateFrom: "2024-11-01",
        dateTo: "2024-11-04",
      },
    ],
    operator: "OR",
  })
  .then(() => {
    //this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
  });
}

